# бесконечно грузится сайт

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-5

я взялся за миграцию сайта с 4.6.2 на 5.0. до меня как я понял создали проект и перенесли код со старыми версиями нугетов. код я поправил и нугеты обновил, выкосил signalR. Startup класс с методами отрабатывает в отладчике, но на контроллерах точки останова не срабатывают. в проекте используется abp (boilerplate). на local iis 503. на iis express бесконечно грузится сайт. помогите разобраться на чём виснет, может логирование нужно включить, но не знаю как.

Comment: смотрите логи своего приложения

Comment: в логах ничего нет, включил отслеживание всех исключений, тогда появились ошибки.